# Como hacer una columna auto incrementa-ble en una tabla que sea de 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, autoincremento

hay alguna función de poder hacer un auto increment numérico de 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. dentro de una tabla?

se que con css puedo hacer el auto increment pero me sale asi: 1, 2, 3, 4
usando esto

```
    table {
    counter-reset: tableCount;     
}
.counterCell:before {              
    content: counter(tableCount); 
    counter-increment: tableCount; 
}
```

y el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacer para que el auto incrementable sea 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ect, por cada tabla generada a partir de mi foreach, es decir la segunta table que sea 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 etc?

así formo mi tabla:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody" id="sortable@(item.Id)" onclick="sortablefuntion(@item.Id);" style="cursor:move;">
    @foreach (var test in item.ConcepList)
    {
    <tr>
        <td class="taskSingleInline counterCell" id="task@(item.Id)" data-taskid="@(item.Id)"></td>
        <td>@test.Concepto</td>
        <td>@test.UnidadDeMedida</td>
        <td>@test.Cantidad</td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters), podrías lograr lo que buscas.

Trayéndolos desde la documentación citada, el ejemplo básico es:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;                       /* Set a counter named 'section', and its initial value is 0. */
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: section;                   /* Increment the value of section counter by 1 */
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";    /* Display the word 'Section ', the value of 
                                                   section counter, and a colon before the content
                                                   of each h3 */
}
```

```html
<h3>Introduction</h3>
<h3>Body</h3>
<h3>Conclusion</h3>
```

Y el ejemplo con varios niveles sería algo como esto:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                /* Creates a new instance of the
                                            section counter with each ol
                                            element */
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;            /* Increments only this instance
                                            of the section counter */
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";   /* Combines the values of all instances
                                            of the section counter, separated
                                            by a period */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 1     -->
  <li>item               <!-- 2     -->
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.1   -->
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.2   -->
      <li>item           <!-- 2.3   -->
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.1 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.2 -->
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.1 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.2 -->
          <li>item</li>  <!-- 2.3.3 -->
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>item</li>      <!-- 2.4   -->
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 3     -->
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 4     -->
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 1     -->
  <li>item</li>          <!-- 2     -->
</ol>
```